# How to add index to a list inside a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary here:

```
dict = {'A':['1','1','1','1','1'], 'B':['2','2'], 'C':['3','3','3','3']}
```

What is the necessary process to get the following result?

```
dict = {'A':['1_01','1_02','1_03','1_04','1_05'], 'B':['2_01','2_02'], 'C':['3_01','3_02','3_03','3_04']}
```

I have been learning python for quite a while now but dictionary is kind of new to me.

Comment: Treat `dict` as just another data type similar to list where you can give names to the indexes. `{"key": "value"}` is the general format for this data type where key acts as index. To iterate through dictionary you use `for key, value in dict_name.items():`. You should also look into docs of pythons on dictionary.

Comment: While this is simple to do the result might be less helpful from data model perspective.

Comment: What do you want to get  when count of items over 10, got `'1-010' `or just `'1-10'`?

Comment: N.B. Since `dict` is a built-in type, you may want to use another name for your variable. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First iterate on keys.

Then loop on keys you are getting on key like for `'A'` value is `['1','1','1','1','1']` then we can change the element at `['1','1','1','1','1']`

`enumerate()` helps you iterate on `index,value` then index starts with zero as per your expected output add 1 to index. As you want the trailing `0` before each count we did `'%02d'% (index+1)`

Like this:

```
dict = {'A':['1','1','1','1','1'], 'B':['2','2'], 'C':['3','3','3','3']}


for i in dict.keys(): #iterate on keys
    for index,val in enumerate(dict[i]): #took value as we have key in i
        element='%02d'% (index+1) #add trailing 0 we converted 1 to int 01
        dict[i][index]=val+"_"+ str(element) #assign new value with converting integer to string

print(dict)
```

Output:

`{'A': ['1_01', '1_02', '1_03', '1_04', '1_05'], 'C': ['3_01', '3_02', '3_03', '3_04'], 'B': ['2_01', '2_02']}`

Answer (score 3):

As others mentioned, refrain from using built-in keywords as variable names, such as `dict`. I kept it for simplicity on your part.

This is probably the most pythonic way of doing it (one line of code):

```
dict = {key:[x+"_0"+str(cnt+1) for cnt,x in enumerate(value)] for key,value in dict.items()}
```

You could also iterate through each dictionary item, and then each list item and manually change the list names as shown below:

```
for key,value in dict.items():
    for cnt,x in enumerate(value):
        dict[key][cnt] = x+"_0"+str(cnt+1)
```

Also, as some others have mentioned, if you want numbers greater than 10 to save as 1_10 rather than 1_010 you can you an if/else statement inside of the list comprehension...

```
dict = {key:[x+"_0"+str(cnt+1) if cnt+1 < 10 else x+"_"+str(cnt+1) for cnt,x in enumerate(value)] for key,value in dict.items()}
```

Comment: This is the clearest answer! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Comment: Mark this as answered if this solved your problem so that others can find it easily!!

Answer (score 2):

Use `enumerate` to iterate over list keeping track of index:

```
d = {'A':['1','1','1','1','1'], 'B':['2','2'], 'C':['3','3','3','3']}

newd = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    newd[k] = [f'{x}_0{i}' for i, x in enumerate(v, 1)]

print(newd)
```

Also a dictionary-comprehension:

```
d = {k: [f'{x}_0{i}' for i, x in enumerate(v, 1)] for k, v in d.items()}
```

**Note**: Don't name your dictionary as `dict` because it shadows the built-in.

Comment: what if count of items over 10,  got `'1-010'`?

Comment: @jiaJimmy, Yes. (assuming that's what OP wants).

Answer (score 2):

```
d= {'A':['1','1','1','1','1'], 'B':['2','2'], 'C':['3','3','3','3']}

{x:[j + '_'+ '{:02}'.format(i+1) for i,j in enumerate(y)] for x,y in d.items()}
```

Comment: To help learning, please spend some time explaining your answer. How and why does it solve OP's problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
adict = {'A':['1','1','1','1','1'], 'B':['2','2'], 'C':['3','3','3','3'], 'D': '23454'}

newdict = {}
for i,v in adict.items():
    if isinstance(v, list):
        count = 0
        for e in v:
            count += 1
            e += '_0' + str(count)
            newdict[i] = newdict.get(i, [e]) + [e]
    else:
        newdict[i] = newdict.get(i, v)

print (newdict)
#{'A': ['1_01', '1_01', '1_02', '1_03', '1_04', '1_05'], 'B': ['2_01', '2_01', '2_02'], 'C': ['3_01', '3_01', '3_02', '3_03', '3_04'], 'D': '23454'}
```

This solution will check for whether your value in the dictionary is a list before assigning an index to it

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictcomp:

```
from itertools import starmap

d = {
    'A': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
    'B': ['2', '2'],
    'C': ['3', '3', '3', '3']
}

f = lambda x, y: '%s_%02d' % (y, x)
print({k: list(starmap(f, enumerate(v, 1))) for k, v in d.items()})
# {'A': ['1_01', '1_02', '1_03', '1_04', '1_05'], 'B': ['2_01', '2_02'], 'C': ['3_01', '3_02', '3_03', '3_04']}
```